# Vim different DiffAdd on two systems

Tags: vim

I have two Vim-s versions with **same** vimrc:

Linux with PuTTY:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar  7 2020 14:11:31)
Included patches: 1-2367
Huge version without GUI.
```

Cygwin with mintty:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug  7 2016 16:06:24)
Included patches: 1-2181
Huge version without GUI.
```

Both have `:colorscheme` as `default`, and `background=dark`.

But `:hi` for Linux: `DiffAdd ... term=bold ctermbg=4`, for Cygwin: `DiffAdd ... term=bold ctermbg=1`. Difference in **ctermbg**. May be not only these.

I can't find where *default* scheme set (there is no `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/default.vim`). I've not found `hi` set in other *vimrc* files (`/etc/vimrc`, `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim`, etc.). And don't understand what *default* scheme is.

I have not modified `$VIMRUNTIME` files, only in `$HOME/.vim`. Why `DiffAdd`-s are different?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@romainl`, you are right, you've point me right place. I've downloaded `vim-7.4.2181-1-src.tar.xz` from [Cygwin Time Machine](http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html) and found in it file `vim-7.4-syncolor.patch` where `vim74/src/syntax.c` patched by *Cygwin*:

```
diff -up vim74/src/syntax.c.syncolor vim74/src/syntax.c
--- vim74/src/syntax.c.syncolor 2014-04-16 15:10:30.362287904 +0200
+++ vim74/src/syntax.c  2014-04-16 15:12:50.278229744 +0200
@@ -6840,8 +6840,8 @@ static char *(highlight_init_light[]) =
    CENT("Visual term=reverse",
         "Visual term=reverse guibg=LightGrey"),
 #ifdef FEAT_DIFF
-   CENT("DiffAdd term=bold ctermbg=LightBlue",
-        "DiffAdd term=bold ctermbg=LightBlue guibg=LightBlue"),
+   CENT("DiffAdd term=bold ctermbg=LightRed",
+        "DiffAdd term=bold ctermbg=LightRed guibg=LightBlue"),
    CENT("DiffChange term=bold ctermbg=LightMagenta",
         "DiffChange term=bold ctermbg=LightMagenta guibg=LightMagenta"),
    CENT("DiffDelete term=bold ctermfg=Blue ctermbg=LightCyan",
@@ -6928,8 +6928,8 @@ static char *(highlight_init_dark[]) =
    CENT("Visual term=reverse",
         "Visual term=reverse guibg=DarkGrey"),
 #ifdef FEAT_DIFF
-   CENT("DiffAdd term=bold ctermbg=DarkBlue",
-        "DiffAdd term=bold ctermbg=DarkBlue guibg=DarkBlue"),
+   CENT("DiffAdd term=bold ctermbg=DarkRed",
+        "DiffAdd term=bold ctermbg=DarkRed guibg=DarkBlue"),
    CENT("DiffChange term=bold ctermbg=DarkMagenta",
         "DiffChange term=bold ctermbg=DarkMagenta guibg=DarkMagenta"),
    CENT("DiffDelete term=bold ctermfg=Blue ctermbg=DarkCyan",
```

Same result is if find `DiffAdd` in both binaries, *LightBlue* (4) and *LightRed* (1).

The reason is found. Now I am calmed down. Thank you very much, `@romainl`!

Answer (score 1):

`default` is not a colorscheme in the same sense as `desert` (for example) is. Vim may or may not be installed with its runtime files, among which its built-in colorschemes. In order to still be capable of providing a "default" colorscheme, the styling attributes of `default` are [hardcoded](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/highlight.c).

That said, `DiffAdd` had a blue background [before the two versions you are using](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/d80629cef03cd40b0bf06c402dfe0b720b3bf608/src/syntax.c#L6964) and [it still does](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/highlight.c#L309) so there is nothing to see, here.

What is the output of the following command in both Vims?

```
:verbose hi DiffAdd
```

Comment: PuTTY: `DiffAdd        xxx term=bold ctermbg=4 guibg=DarkBlue
        Last set from /.vimrc` (`/` is $HOME), Cygwi: `DiffAdd        xxx term=bold ctermbg=1 guibg=DarkBlue
        Last set from ~/.vim/vimrc`.

Comment: Linux version build from source, Cygwin dowloaded from cygwin.com as binary

Comment: That's not the same `vimrc`. Can we see both?

Comment: `@romainl`, that's the same `vimrc` by contents, different machines and OS.